# javascript content slider displaying only first slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a text slider on my [home page](http://frshstudio.com/#home), that should display slides individually according to which arrow is selected. Currently, only the first slide is showing and each slide thereafter is blank. What am I missing to make each individual slide show?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EeWVc/2/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // Setup Variables
    var slides = $('#slider_mask .slide_container').children();
    var total_slides = slides.children().length;
    var slide_width = $('#slider_mask').width();
    var current_slide = 0;

    slides.not(':first').hide();
    // Set the width of the slide_container to total width of all slides
    $('#slider_mask .slide_container').width(slide_width*total_slides);

    // Handle Right Arrow Click
    $('#slider_mask .right_button').on('click', function() {

        current_slide++;

        if(current_slide == total_slides){ current_slide = 0; }

        var negative_margin_required = current_slide*slide_width;
        $('#slider_mask .slide_container').stop().animate({marginLeft:-negative_margin_required+'px'},'fast');


    });

    // Handle Left Arrow Click
    $('#slider_mask .left_button').on('click', function() {

        current_slide--;

        if(current_slide < 0){ current_slide = total_slides-1; }

        var negative_margin_required = current_slide*slide_width;
        $('#slider_mask .slide_container').stop().animate({marginLeft:-negative_margin_required+'px'},'fast');

    });
});
```

Comment: Solved that issue -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/EeWVc/1/). Now all you have to do is create a working slider ?

Comment: @adeneo Thanks for the fiddle. I implemented your new code, but now the slider only shows the first slide, and every click of the arrow thereafter shows a blank slide. Any idea whats going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fFkNb/1/). I scaled it down to a minimum.

I started with the slider mask having the fixed width and set the other widths off of that.

Ludovico Grossi is correct about making the slide element float left. When they are "block" elements without the float, they stack. If they are changed to "inline" elements, they cannot have a fixed width. It worked to set them to "inline-block", but I don't know if that is supported in all browsers. Having them as "block" and float left works.

I also had to make some other changes. One of which was that the `.animate()` function does not cause a hidden element to be shown. It says this on the [documenation page](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). Instead of hiding the slides by calling `.hide()`, they simply are out of view by having overflow set to hidden for the mask element.

I also put the text-align center on the slide elements, rather than the container element.

UPDATE:

I created another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WMF2N/) that starts with the code from [adeneo's fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/EeWVc/1/) and includes the necessary changes. I put comments next to all the code and CSS that was added, removed, or changed. I had to make one change to the html. I added the `<div id="home">` element that wraps everything. Without it the CSS selectors don't match anything.

Comment: I appreciate your time and efforts on this. What you've said makes sense, however if you check the above link to my home page, you'll see that the slider is now displaying all three slides at once..?

Comment: @AMC - I just tried your home page with Firefox 19, Chrome 25, and IE 9. It worked great on all three. Of course, I had been to your home page before with Firefox, so it didn't work at first because Firefox had your CSS file cached. I had to hold down the Shift key while I clicked the Reload button to clear the browser's cache. Then it worked fine.

Comment: @AMC - It must be working for you now. In case it was an issue with the browser caching the CSS file, I checked and that file is set to be cached for 30 days. If you are worried that users will have it cached, what you can do is rename the file by adding a version number to it, like `styles-2.css`, and then increment the number each time the file changes. Of course, this means you must change and republish all the pages that reference that file. That's the trade-off.

Answer (score 1):

Check your css:

slide: fixed width, float left.

container: width n_slide * slide_(outer)_width

slide mask: the same as a single slide width, overflow hidden.